# Read double from void * buffer

Tags: c

Please excuse my lack of understanding, I'm a beginner with C. So, I have a `void *` buffer that I `calloc` like this:

`void * dataBuffer = calloc(samples, sizeof(double));`

and would like to later read it like this:

`double myDoubleDB = dataBuffer[sampleIndex];`

but I get an error because they are of different types (void and double).

How can I achieve this? My arch is ARM and I'm using GCC to compile

UPDATE: `dataBuffer` is out of my reach (other library) and it simply comes as `void *`

Comment: Why is your original buffer `void *` ? What does it actually contain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can make it a pointer to `double` in the first place, so much the better.

```
double * dataBuffer = calloc(samples, sizeof *dataBuffer);
double myDoubleDB = dataBuffer[sampleIndex];
```

Otherwise, just **unsafely** explicitly convert the `void*` to `double*` with a cast:

```
void * dataBuffer = calloc(samples, sizeof (double));
double myDoubleDB = ((double*)dataBuffer)[sampleIndex];
```

Comment: `dataBuffer` is out of my reach (other library) and it simply comes as `void *`. Why **unsafely**? Can you please explain or give me some link to read about it?

Comment: @ValentinRadu Then you should have said so in your question and casting is your only chance.

Comment: Unless there are other guarantees (which the other library possibly provides) it is unsafe because some requirements for `double*` are greater than the same requirements for `void*`: specifically size requirements for one.

Comment: @pmg: Could you please elaborate? How does this fit to "A pointer to any ... type may be converted to a pointer to void
and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer" (6.3.2.3)?

Comment: The key words in that quote are "convert back again". It the pointer started as `double*` and got converted to `void*`, it can safely be **converted back** to `double*`. It is unsafe (though allowed **and unsafe** with a cast) to convert it to `struct tm*` for instance.

Comment: @pmg: So for the specific example, `dataBuffer` could hold an address which is not valid for a `double`? `calloc` could return such an address?

Comment: `calloc` returns an address that can be used by a pointer to any type, **provided enough space was allocated**. But you say the pointer comes from "other library" ... do you know it was created with `calloc`?

Answer (score 4):

```
double *dataBuffer = calloc(samples, sizeof(double));
```

Note that 2 bytes will probably not be enough for a `double`.

Note also that all bits 0 in memory (as provided by `calloc`) do not necessarily represent a valid `double` value (on most platforms, it will, see IEEE754).

If you cannot change the declaration of `dataBuffer`, you should still correct the `calloc` and then cast (as proposed by others):

```
double myDoubleDB = ((double*)dataBuffer)[sampleIndex];
```

Comment: `calloc` multiplies the two arguments to find how many bytes to allocate

Comment: @pmg: yes, and assuming `samples`is the number of array elements, Valentin allocated just 2 bytes per element.

Comment: Whereas you generally are right, normally (on an IEEE 754-based platform) it is a valid double (0.0). But I'm not the downvoter, +1 for the correct size.

Comment: user pmg said that casting like this is **unsafe**, any idea why?

Comment: @Valentin Radu: Because you get no compiler type checks that way.

Answer (score 1):

You need some casting :

```
double myDoubleDB = ((double*)dataBuffer)[sampleIndex];
```

*Note: it is better use pointer to `double` instead of `void` for simplicity.*

According to new update:

You can use a pointer to reduce castings:

```
double *doubleDataBuffer = (double*) dataBuffer;
double myDoubleDB = doubleDataBuffer[sampleIndex];
```